# RxJava asynchronous observer misses elements

Tags: rx-java

I am using observeOn to observe an observable in another thread:

```
Observable.just("Hello", "world!").observeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe(System.out::println);
```

However this code will not *always* output "Hello world!". The same happens with a PublishSubject:

```
PublishSubject<String> subject = PublishSubject.create();
subject.observeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe(System.out::println);
subject.onNext("Hello");
subject.onNext("world!");
```

Why does this code not always print "Hello world!" ? I thought that at least in the second sample the subscribe would receive both message since it subscribes before the onNext calls. Is there a way to receive both messages ?

Comment: Are you really want to use Schedulers.io() here? According to the docs it should be used only for IO operations such as file reading or network.

Comment: The use of io() is irrelevant from the point of view of the underlying problem. It is intended for blocking operations, usually IO, but nothing stops you from doing computation on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Threads underlying RxJava schedulers are all daemon threads and they are stopped by the JVM if all other non-daemon threads have completed. If you run your examples from `static void main()`, it is very likely your `main()` method will terminate before the other threads had a chance of running and thus the print code is not executed.

Depending on how you want to observe a sequence, you can use `toBlocking()` on the Observable chain or use a `CountDownLatch` and `countDown()` in your `onCompleted()` method implementation.

Comment: Thanks, this was indeed the issue ! I used theCountDownLatch to prevent the issue. However I am not sure I understand well the semantic of toBlocking. Does that make the calling thread block until onCompleted is called ?

Comment: Methods on the BlockingObservable execute on the current thread and are blocking in nature. Some exhaustive methods will keep blocking until the upstream terminates with onComplete or onError.

Answer (score 0):

IO scheduler need some time to be ready.

When you emit items using onNext it is not yet ready so you missed it.

Comment: This answer is a bit misleading: if given enough time, they will process the onNext without data loss, but the example progam quits before the processing can happen.